# Starting a bounty on another user's question

Tags: discussion, bounty

Can I start a bounty on another user's question who has accepted the answer but it doesn't answer my doubts and the question has become inactive?

Comment: Sure, why not? There's an "improve details" bounty reason, among other things.

Comment: There is also a custom text block you can add explaining the reason for offering the bounty.  Since you are a fairly new user, I'd be willing to post a bounty for you if you add the specific Question and what doubts about it you'd like resolved.  Chances are if you've seen a gap in the reasoning, other Readers may benefit from the same clarification.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please tell us which question is that? Note my my answer to your question is affirmative no matter what the question is.

Comment: was something like this-"multiplication of probability" under independent events"

Answer (score 11):

Sure, I do it all the time. Just make sure you leave a comment explaining what you want from the new answers.